# Selenium: Button in modal content is not clickable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to Click the "OK" button during a Selenium test but the Element is not visible.

```javascript
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"5f6e7b16-0fa1-4db6-869b-3a6ba6b0fafe\"]")).click();
```

```html
<div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="5a4bb849-7a61-4603-9ef2-f9e0ecab4523">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="f7f4b18b-2ba2-4c1e-b541-a254c080f398">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Ok
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Selenium doesn't click invisible elements

Comment: any idea for workaround?

Comment: You can inject Java Script!

Comment: @ceddyy, are you able to see 'Ok' button in modal? or not.

Comment: @BhavinDholakiya yes.

Comment: @ceddy, then try my answer. and if work then marks as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your DOM, the button id is changing dynamically. Whenever page reload it will generating new id. There is different button id you used in your Selenium code and HTML. So, I suggest you go with `className`. Try below code and hope it works for you.

```
        //If the Element is not visible then wait until that element is not visible
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("btn btn-warning")));

        //If the element is visible but not Clickable then wait until that element get Clickable.       
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("btn btn-warning")));

        //Then simply click the button
        driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-warning")).click();
```

Comment: Welcome, you may [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavascriptExecutor to click the element,

Refer code,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"5f6e7b16-0fa1-4db6-869b-3a6ba6b0fafe\"]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: @ceddyyy can you please explain what was the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared it seems that the desired element is within a *Bootstrap Modal Dialog Box* and the `id` attribute of the element is dynamic. So to invoke `click()` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

- **cssSelector** :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons button.btn.btn-warning"))).click();
  ```
- **xpath** :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons']//button[@class='btn btn-warning']"))).click();
  ```