# Click on "accept cookie" in a website with Python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Iam trying to click on the "accept cookie" button on a website. In general, it does work easily by locating it with xpath. But in the website "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Default.aspx" its getting hard to click on accept cookie button, goes by button name as "Tamam".

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/a[1]").click()
```

Iam trying to click with the above code but it seems to be not working with various changes in time and frame. Please help me out in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is reliably named Taman, try using find element by name:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('Taman').click()
```

Comment: no still not catching the name, or class. I tried to change to the frame too but somehow browser cant detect it.

Comment: Are you sure that the modal exists when your code attempts to find it? You may have to wait until the DOM makes it visible. Here's a post that speaks to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50055096/13918725